# Background function that works automatically in a time interval

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm working with codeigniter, and i'm a beginner.
I want to run a controller function that runs in background and triggers automatically every 1 minute continuously. I tried cron job but it has to visit the url.

Comment: Well, you should not try to run a frontend controller's action from cron or other background processes. Usually, you need a separate module for those processes. They can share managers/services with frontend modules though.

Comment: can you please explain more.?

Comment: CodeIgniter calls it "running via CLI" process. It has CI_Controller that you can extend. Through that controller you can access other modules/services/managers. Check [CodeIgniter CLI documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html) out

Comment: You can use cronjob like this: `*/1 * * * * wget http://example.com/check` otherwise you can use php program looping forever, running in your console .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by cron job. It was my mistake that I didn't use the correct command line for cron job.
I have to use

```
    curl --silent https://www.example.com/controller_function_name
```